# Error on doing shutil.rmtree

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil

In my python code am copying some installer to temp and installing that and then I want to delete the temp copy. 
I am using "shutil.rmtree" function to remove the installer copy in the temp.
Sometime I am getting an error like **"[Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"**

How can I avoid that ? Do  we have a way to check a directory is not used by any other program ? If yes can we check for the availability of directory till the other process leaves control and delete it ?

Please help me with sample codes ! I am pretty new to python.

```
copy_dst = tempfile.mkdtemp()

if success:
    success = robocopy_file_or_folder(installer_location, copy_dst)

local_path_to_setup = os.path.join(copy_dst, app_folder, 'setup.exe')

if success:
    success, response_text = install_product(local_path_to_setup, success, response_text)
try:
    if success:
        shutil.rmtree(copy_dst, ignore_errors = False, onerror=handle_remove_readonly)
except OSError as e:
    log("      %s\n      Delete installer Local Copy at \"%s\" failed.\n" % (e, copy_dst))
    success = False
```

This is the code !! and "install_product()" will install the product by calling the setup.exe in another command.robocopy_file_or_folder () -- will copy the files.

```
def handle_remove_readonly(func, path, exc):
"""
Changes the access mode of the specified folder to remove read_only
"""
exc_value = exc[1]
if func in (os.rmdir, os.remove) and exc_value.errno == errno.EACCES:
    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRWXU| stat.S_IRWXG| stat.S_IRWXO) # 0777
    func(path)
else:
    raise
```

Comment: Please copy paste the code, which you have written

Comment: How do you mean avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

> "`install_product()`" will install the product by calling the setup.exe in another `command.robocopy_file_or_folder()` – will copy the files.

Wait for the installation to finish and `setup.exe` to exit before trying to remove the directory.

Comment: I am using start /wait cmd \c for running the setup.exe. So it should be waiting till the installation completion

Comment: It is in the install_product() function.